# What is efficient way to align 32 bit data using c

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm looking for best methods to handle the **alignment boundaries** while that will helpful to work with systems for **8/16/32 bit** target systems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You are are going to need to explain what you are concerned about a good deal more carefully.  For the most part, the compiler takes care of the issue for you.  If you want to do something that the compiler doesn't handle automatically, you need to specify what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHAR_BIT. For example: if you define mask, you can always use it as mask*CHAR_BIT. check limits.h for more information